# QuickSort in Python. Increment in array trouble

Tags: python, increment, quicksort

I am trying to implement quicksort in python. Problem is how to increment/decrement value of i/j in array `a`. I know that I should write `i=i+1` and there are no such thing like `i++` in python, but I don't understand in which way I should do this.
I am newbie, here is my code.

```
def quicksort(a,lo,hi):
    if(hi<=lo):
        return
    i = lo - 1
    j = hi
    v = a[hi]

    while True:
        while(a[++i] < v):
            pass

        while(v < a[--j]):
            if(j==lo):
                break
        if(i>=j):
            break
        t = a[i]
        a[i] = a[j]
        a[j] = t

    t = a[i]
    a[i] = a[hi]
    a[hi] = t
    quicksort(a, lo, i - 1)
    quicksort(a, i + 1, hi)
```

Answer (score 0):

in python, you cannot assign and get the value, that's an intentional limitation to avoid issues with typos, find the proper sequence point...

You have no choice than to "emulate" the C-ported code:

```
    while(a[++i] < v):
        pass

    while(v < a[--j]):
        if(j==lo):
            break
```

(note that both constructs generate an infinite loop because:

```
++i == i
```

and

```
--j == j
```

(applying unary plus any number of times or unary minus an even number of times gives the same number, see [Why Don't Two Plus Operators Throw an Error (e.g., 1 + + 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41936285/why-dont-two-plus-operators-throw-an-error-e-g-1-2/41936327#41936327))

So change to:

```
    i += 1
    while(a[i] < v):
        i += 1

    j -= 1
    while(v < a[j]):
        if(j==lo):
            break
        j -= 1
```

Comment: Thank you,  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The following construct does not work the same way in Python as it does in C++:

`while(a[++i] < v):`

as well as this one:

`while(v < a[--j]):`

The way you change the code is the following:

```
def quicksort(a,lo,hi):
    if(hi<=lo):
        return
    i = lo - 1
    j = hi
    v = a[hi]

    while True:
        i += 1
        while(a[i] < v):
            i += 1
            pass

        j -= 1
        while(v < a[j]):
            j -= 1
            if(j==lo):
                break
        if(i>=j):
            break
        t = a[i]
        a[i] = a[j]
        a[j] = t

    t = a[i]
    a[i] = a[hi]
    a[hi] = t
    quicksort(a, lo, i - 1)
    quicksort(a, i + 1, hi)
```

Comment: illegal? have you tried to make it run/compile it? BTW, your code isn't equivalent to what OP wants.

Comment: compile? Are we talking about Python?